# Conditional formating not working if formula includes text

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H10)," ",SUM(H10-TODAY()))&" days to ship"
```

If I enter the above formula, the conditional formatting works fine. But when I enter any text, like `"days to ship"` in the formula the conditional formatting stops working altogether.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, John. I'm a little confused. What is the condition that you set for the conditional formatting? Guessing, I'd say you need to use the formula SUM..etc. as the conditional formula.

Answer (score 0):

Could use more information.

Formatting is only applied when the condition equals True. If the condition is False it just does not change the formatting.

If you want to format a cell whether it is blank or whether it has "days to ship"

Your Formula rewritten a bit to show blank if H10 is blank. Cell I10 `=IF(H10="","",H10-TODAY()&" days to ship")`

Conditional Formula to apply to cell I10 `=(ISNUMBER(LEFT(I10,1)+0))`

This will check if there is a number in front of the days to ship text and when true format the cell accordingly.

I hope this helps